# How to add to customer wishlist in Magento Admin

Tags: wishlist, ce-1.9.1.0

Any idea how I can add products to a customer's wishlist in the admin backend? Being able to do this would greatly simplify the experience for some of my corporate customers who just wish to be able to sign in, look at their wishlist products and order.

I've done some Google searching for answers but not finding anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way, but it's very counter-intuitive.

- Edit the desired customer in the backend.
- Click on create order
- Select one of the stores
- Click on the "Add products" button on the right.
- Find the products you want to add to the wishlist and check the checkbox on the desired rows.
- Click on "Add selected products to order".
- On the dropdown near each item you should see an option "Move to wishlist". Select it and  click on "Update Items Qtys".

But there is a catch.
It only works if the customer already has a whishlist. It can be empty but it has to exist.
To check this, you have to look in the `wishlit` table. Search for a record with `customer_id` = your customer id.

If there is none, it won't work. But you can add it with a simple insert in the same table.

If this is not a suitable solution you can try to login as the customer and add his/her products to the wishlist.

[Here is a full functioning module that allows you to do that.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/11480/146)

Comment: Thank you Marius that did work perfectly. As far as if the customer has a wishlist - isn't it standard (assuming you have it turned on in the config) that every registered customer has a wishlist? That's how it appears to me anyway so I should be set with this solution. However round-about it may be, it works perfect.

Comment: Good find! These steps also work for Magento 2.