# Magento 1: implementing an autologin link in an email

Tags: magento-1.9, module, customer, magento-1, security

So the idea is to **have a link in the email that automatically logs a customer in when clicked.**

I know it is **critical especially in terms of security**, here's what I've got for now:

- store the generated links in a database table
- generate a random hash value stored against the customer id
- both hash and customer id in the URL
- in case the hash does not match the one stored for the customer_id, reset the hash (to avoid brute forcing)
- make the links one use only
- set an expiration time on the links

I'm looking for any good recommendation on this approach, and how can I improve it ? What did I miss ? What are the risks left with such approach and how to overcome them ?

Comment: Hi, I think this is a general Web Application Security question. You should better ask it here: security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have to add: I appreciate the question itself and also what you've already thought about, but it's not a Magento specific question. :)

Comment: I've posted a similar question a million years ago: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/10209/146 It was about loging in as a customer from the backend. Maybe you can use that and adapt it to your needs. As for risks, you look like you already know them.

Comment: @Marius if you're interested http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129846/implementing-an-autologin-link-in-an-email/129850#129850

Comment: @AnnaVölkl if you're interested http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129846/implementing-an-autologin-link-in-an-email/129850#129850

Comment: What do you think, Raphael? Does it seem like Marius's answer is the solution you need?

Comment: @benmarks see the security SE link I posted in the comments, I reckon that' s a similar approach

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism now that's an awesome answer on the infosec SE :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those wondering here's the idea based on the answer I got here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129846/implementing-an-autologin-link-in-an-email/129850#129850:

### Database table

It will containg the links

- link id
- token hash
- customer email
- expiration date

### Link protection

To make them secure, **the link token should have at least 72 bits of entropy** (9 bytes, or 12 Base64 characters) but **you need to use an internal PHP random generator or read bytes directly from `/dev/urandom`.** Have a read at this article to understand how most of the PHP random methods are not really random: http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Insufficient-Entropy-For-Random-Values.html?highlight=hash

**In the database you need to store the hash of the token and not the token itself** in case the database is stolen so the token can only be seen in the email.

### Securing your custom controller

Every link must be secured thus you need to add the following for your custom route in your `config.xml`

```
<frontend>
    <secure_url>
        <custom>/custom/</custom>
    </secure_url>
</frontend>
```

Then when you generate the URL don't forget to make the URL secure:

```
Mage::getUrl('custom',array('_secure'=>true));
```

### One use only

In your custom controller you'll have to retrieve the token parameter then look for a corresponding entry in the database table that matches the hash. If found, **retrieve the corresponding customer email and delete the corresponding link row in the database**

After that you can log in your customer the standard way.

### Expiration time

Choose a relatively small expiration time: 24, 48, 72 hours.

Whenever you create a link set the expiration time as today + expiration.

Then you need a cronjob that runs every 5 minutes and that generates a collection of links where the expiration date is less or equal to today datetime.

And delete all those entries.